# Loop through a multidimensional array in bash 4

Tags: bash, array

I want to define a hash list in bash (version 4.3.30):

- 4 gateways
- each gateway has

  - an IP
  - an IP6
  - a name
  - ...

and I want to walk through this list in a loop and do stuff to each gateway.

I searched a lot, but it seems, bash doesn't support multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bash` doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays yet. Only `ksh93` does.

Here, you can use a csv-like structure and you don't even need to use arrays:

```
#! /bin/sh -
gws="\
foo,1.1.1.12,1::1
blah,2.2.2.2,2::2"

while IFS=, read name ip4 ip6; do
  echo something with "$name" "$ip4"...
done << E
$gws
E
```

(you don't even need bash)

With `ksh93`:

```
gws=(
  (name=foo  ip4=1.1.1.1 ip6=1::1)
  (name=blah ip4=2.2.2.2 ip6=1::2)
)

printf '%s\n' "${gws[0].name}"
```

Comment: Can you fill in  the `<< E
$gws
E` in the beginning somehow?

Comment: @rubo77, no, but you could use a function if you want to make it neater.

Comment: @rubo77, I just meant `process_gws() while...; done; process_gws <<...` which you may find neater. That's all cosmetic considerations.

Comment: It should work fine as is.  Bash lets you use `<<< "$gws"` to redirect from a string, instead of needing a multi-line here-document.  But either construct should work in a function.

Comment: @rubo77, in that case, the while loop runs in a subshell.

Comment: You can put the array before the while loop at the beginning without funkćtion: `cat <<< "$gws" | while IFS ...`